# Inherit DateField from another model (Django)

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django database storing 'episodes' and 'reviews'. Each episode has a title, a date and a set of reviews. Each review has a title, a score, and must belong to an episode. I'd also like the review to inherit a DateField from the episode it belongs to.

I know that there's no 'need' for this as the date of each review can be found by cross-referencing with the episode it belongs to via the `ForeignKey`. I'm simply asking can this be done and how?

My example `models.py` code:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()

class Review(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    score = models.FloatField()
    episode = models.ForeignKey(Episode)
```

So I'd like to include a property in `Review` called `date` that inherits the date from its `Episode` when they are both being created.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a ForeignKey on Review pointing towards Episode? If not, you should add it.

Then you can simply traverse that relationship to get the date from the Episode when you have the review. There's no need to add a date field on Review.

Comment: I've added the `ForeignKey` that was missing from my my original post. I did state in the question that I could do it the way you have suggested. However, my question was whether there was a way to inherit the date rather than traversing the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to use `class Meta: abstract = True`

```
class DateModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    # you could in fact include the title field here as well
    # since they have that in common too. 

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Episode(DateModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Review(DateModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    score = models.FloatField()
    episode = models.ForeignKey(Episode)
```

Episode and Review will inherit the date field from DateModel, this is a cleaner layout than adding the date field to both models themselves. I assume that you would like to keep these two fields in sync? So whenever you update the `Episode` you would also need to update the `Review` and vice versa. So the better option is to keep having a normalized model as you had from the beginning.

You mentioned that you would like to add this property when Episode gets created. [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/signals/) can do that for you.